# 2017 Accord Sport Special Edition -- Can it support Android Auto?

Tags: honda

Is it possible for this model to support Apple Carplay or Android Auto? (in the stock entertainment system)

Comment: A search of the question title quickly reveals *"Apple CarPlay and Android Auto were first available on the Honda Accord and Honda Civic for the 2016 model year."* But was it an option? Consult the owner's handbook and try to connect.

Comment: Which trim level? I'm sure that it will work out of the box in higher trim levels. For the LX, I'm not so sure.